# $\int f(x)\sin(2x) \ge f(\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given $f : [0, +\infty) \to \Bbb R$ a function monotone decreasing and continuous:

Show that:

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\sin(2x) dx \ge f(\pi/2)$$

---

And

If $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\sin(2x) dx = f(\pi/2)$$

Then f must be constant.

---

I know that

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2x) dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x) dx = 1$$

And that the absolute value of the function $f(x)\sin(2x)$ must be smaller then the absolute value of $f(x)$ because $\sin(2x)$ in that interval is always smaller than one (equal to 1 for $x=\pi/4$).

I also thought about possibly applying the mean value theorem, or the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I do not know how to actually proceed.

For the second one

If $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\sin(2x) dx = f(\pi/2)$$

$$f(x) = k = f(\pi/2)$$

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} k\sin(2x) dx =  k\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2x) dx = k\times 1 = k = f(\pi/2)$$

But I have not shown that if the integral is 1 then the function must be constant, only the reverse, that given a constant function the integral is $f(\pi/2)$. What if there are other functions non-constant for which this is true?

Answer that give hints and incomplete solutions are encouraged, because I would like to solve this as much by myself as possible.

This graph may be useful (limited to the case where f(x)=-mx) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rwy5i9mcgp

Comment: @copper.hat you mean sin(2x) right?

Comment: Yes, and note that $\sin$ is non negative on the interval in question (otherwise the inequality would not hold).

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is decreasing we have on $[0,\pi/2]$: $f(x) \geq f(\pi/2)$, so we have $$f(x) \sin 2x \geq f(\pi/2) \sin(2x)$$ and thus

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\sin(2x) dx \ge  \int_0^{\pi/2}f(\pi/2) \sin(2x)dx =  f(\pi/2)\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2x) dx= f(\pi/2)$$

Comment: Thanks, how can I show that there are no functions that are non-constant for which the second case (equality) is true?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In general, if $g(x) \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$ and is continuous, then if
$\int_a^b g(x) dx = 0$ then we must have $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

Details:

> In this case take $g(x) = (f(x)-f({\pi \over 2})) \sin (2x)$.